# Unable to boot to Windows 10 after installing Centos 7 x_86-64 minimal

Tags: centos, partition, grub2, dual-boot

I have been trying to install CentOS x_86-64 minimal atop windows 10 & it went into a complete mess with lots of issues the first and foremost being unable to see an option for dual boot for Windows. I have tried a couple of methods following the suggestions from internet like trying to generate grub2 config file by using `grub2-mkconfig`, but the windows image was not listed there though `ntfs-3g` package is already installed. Then I tried to edit `/etc/default/grub` to set `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true`, edit `grub.d/40_custom` to manually create entry for Windows with UUID & then tried re-generating the grub config file which still doesn't list Windows partition (only lists 4 images all of which are `/boot/vmlinuz` & `/boot/initramfs` type). Also tried to install Xorg to attempt to actually 'view' these settings in GUI & edit, but Xorg is also not launching due to some reason & remains stuck showing "aiglx suspending aiglx clients for vt switch".

Note: I was not able to find the `/dev/sd**` id using `fdisk -l` since it didn't list such detail, so used the UUID of sda1 using blkid `/dev/sda1` while editing `grub.d/40_custom` file.

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: gpt
Disk identifier: 846FED61-FF90-4589-8BBF-5DCAD289AC58


    #         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
     1         2048      1085439    529M  Windows recover Basic data partition
     2      1085440      1290239    100M  EFI System      EFI system partition
     3      1290240      1323007     16M  Microsoft reser Microsoft reserved partition
     4      1323008    256886783  121.9G  Microsoft basic Basic data partition
     5    256886784    256888831      1M  Microsoft basic Basic data partition
     6    256888832    263282687    3.1G  Microsoft basic Basic data partition
     7   1185740800   1185742847      1M  Microsoft basic Basic data partition
     8   1185742848   1953521663  366.1G  Microsoft basic Basic data partition
     9    263282688    263284735      1M  BIOS boot       
    10    263284736    265381887      1G  Microsoft basic 
    11    265381888   1185740799  438.9G  Linux LVM       

Disk /dev/mapper/centos-root: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/centos-swap: 4160 MB, 4160749568 bytes, 8126464 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/centos-home: 413.4 GB, 413369630720 bytes, 807362560 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdd: 32.0 GB, 32015679488 bytes, 62530624 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x013780ef


       Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
    /dev/sdd1   *        2048    62530623    31264288    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Can someone please help on the above issue ?

Comment: Did you install Centos in UEFI boot mode? You show an ESP and typical partitions for Windows in UEFI boot mode on a gpt partitioned drive.  But you show a bios_grub partition which is only required for BIOS boot on gpt partitioned drives. Grub can only boot other installs in same boot mode. And Windows fast start up must be off.  You just need to reinstall grub in UEFI boot mode, it will use existing ESP.

Comment: You can tell if Centos was installed and booted as an EFI OS if there is a `/sys/firmware/efi/` directory. If it isn’t present, you’ve booted using the Compatibility Support Module (CSM), i.e. legacy or BIOS boot.

Comment: Hi @oldfred, thanks for your reply. However can you please provide some pointers in this regard. when I search for "reinstall grub in UEFI boot mode" the results are mostly Ubuntu specific & it asks us to boot using the installation media & go with "Try  without installing option" where as I get only these options  1. Install CentOs7, Test this media & install CentOs7 & Troubleshooting

Comment: Do not know Centos. But how you boot install media UEFI or BIOS, is also how it repairs. So you should be able to boot in UEFI mode and make UEFI repairs or reinstall grub in UEFI Mode, if not already UEFI. Grub typically uses the Windows ESP, and most systems only support one ESP - efi system partition per drive/device.  May be similar? http://askubuntu.com/questions/854215/dual-booting-regular-ubuntu-with-lvm-fedora/854235#854235 LVM chroot
http://askubuntu.com/questions/719409/how-to-reinstall-grub-from-a-liveusb-if-the-partition-is-encrypted-and-there-i?rq=1

Comment: Hi @jsbillings, thanks for your reply, I see there is a firmware/efi folder present which has sub folders - config_table, efivars, fw_platform_size, fw_vendor, mok_variables, runtime-map, systab, vars

Comment: Hi @oldfred, thanks a ton for suggesting the above solution, I think I have moved a step closer with the Windows 10 option was shown once after I installed the lvm2 package, but I got an error which read something like /bootmgr not found when I selected the Windows boot. After this I booted again onto Centos & reverted the changes which I made previously with the default/grub & 40_custom files assuming it has something to do with the error message, but now again I lost the Windows boot option. Has this something to do with these changes and any idea to proceed ?.

Comment: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Hi @oldfred I am unable to follow the instructions since its ubuntu specific & I have yum instead of apt-get. but following lead from your suggestion, & https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-rhel-7-how-to-reinstall-grub2-from-rescue-mode/ for Centos OS, for which I have followed until chroot, however with step2, i.e egrub2-install /dev/sda, I got an error stating unable to find device for /boot/grub2. Subsequently, tried to mount my devices manually following instructions from internet, but noticed that my /dev/ folder doesn't have any devices/directories present after Step #1.

Comment: Grub only boots working Windows. That includes Windows fast start up must be off. Windows updates may turn fast start up back on. An advantage of UEFI is that you should be able to directly boot Windows from UEFI and potentially run repairs or turn off fast start up again. But always best to have current version Windows repair flash drive & live installer or other Linux repair flash drives.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the case on CentOS, but in Fedora (the "incubator" for RedHat/CentOS), the minimal selection doesn't install the program `which`, needed by `os-prober`. Try to do `sudo yum install which` or `sudo dnf install which` at a command prompt, then try again, as root, `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` (this is on Fedora, check your configuration to find the precise location of `grub.cfg`). Then grub configuration will be updated, providing also an option for loading Windows.